# Optimal control of an integrator

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

> Given the control problem $$ \max_{u \in [0,1]} \int_0^{10} x (t) \,{\rm d} t \quad \text{subject to} \quad \dot x = u, \quad x(0)=0, \quad x(10)=2$$ 
>  a) Find the solution $(x_∗,u_∗)$ that satisfies the Maximum Principle. 
>  b) Motivate whether the solution found is optimal or not. 
>  c) Compute the value $V$ of the objective function corresponding to the optimal solution.

Comment: Where is your work?

Comment: You can solve this geometrically and then confirm that it is correct using Pontryagin's MP.